# How to prove that $k(x)$ is not complete in the $x$-adic metric

Tags: metric-spaces, field-theory, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

It is not hard to find proofs showing that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not complete with respect to the metric induced by the valuation $|\;\;|_p$.
For example, it is enough to recall that every complete metric space is Baire and to show that $(\mathbb{Q},|\;\;|_p)$ is not Baire.
Another option is to show that $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is uncountable, so $(\mathbb{Q},|\;\;|_p)$ is different than its completion.
Both arguments use the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable.

But when I try to justify that $k(x)$ is not complete in the metric induced by the $x$-adic valuation $|\;\;|_x$, I don't find ideas or references addressing the proof.
How can I proof the incompleteness of $(k(x), |\;\;|_x)$ without invoking its completion field $k((x))$? Any reference?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720517

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228422/

Comment: What is the rationale behind "without invoking its completion field"? A space is complete iff it equals its completion. One can even use that as a definition. Any proof showing a space is incomplete can easily be translated into showing that it is not equal to its completion, and vice versa. (We have to show: "There is a Cauchy sequence which does not converge in the space"; you can show that by assuming it had a limit in the space and derive a contradiction; I can, with the same contradiction argument, show that the *limit which it has in its completion* does not lie in the original space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying and researching several days, I couldn't prove the result without invoking $K((x))$. So here is what I can do.

**Definition:** Let $K$ be a field. A sequence $(r_n)_n$ of elements of $K$ is  *linearly recurrent*
if there exist constants $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_k\in K$ such that 
\begin{equation}\label{linear recurrence}
r_{n+k}=c_1r_{n}+c_2r_{n+1}+\cdots+c_kr_{n+k-1}
\end{equation}
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

> **Theorem:** Let $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty r_ix^i\in K[[x]]$, where $K$ is any field. For $m,s\geq0$, let $A_{s,m}$ be the matrix
>   $\{r_{s+i+j}\}_{0\leq i,j\leq m}$:
>
> \begin{pmatrix} r_s & r_{s+1} & r_{s+2} & \cdots & r_{s+m} \\ 
>  r_{s+1} & r_{s+2} & r_{s+3} & \cdots & r_{s+m+1} \\  r_{s+2} & r_{s+3} &
>  r_{s+4} & \cdots & r_{s+m+2} \\  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots
>  \\  r_{s+m} & r_{s+m+1} & r_{s+m+2} & \cdots & r_{s+2m} \end{pmatrix}
>
> and let $N_{s,m}:=\det(A_{s,m})$. Then $f(x)\in K(x)$ if and only if
>   there exist integers $m\geq0$ and $S$ such that $N_{s,m}=0$ whenever
>   $s\geq S$, or equivalently, if the sequence $(r_n)_n$ is eventually
>   linearly recurrent.
>
> **Proof:** See V.5. Lemma 5 of  Koblitz, N., "p-adic Numbers, p-adic Analysis, and Zeta-Functions." Vol. 58. Springer Science and Business
>   Media, 2012. Also see  III.3.1.N  of Ribenboim, P., "The theory of
>   classical valuations." Springer Science and Business Media, 1999.

Now we are in  position to prove the incompleteness of $(K(x),|\;\;|_x)$.
Let $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^{i^2}\in K((x))$. 
Notice that $f(x)$ is the limit of a sequence of rational functions, 
say $a_n(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n x^{i^2}\in K[x]$.
Thus $(a_n(x))_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $K(x)$. We will show that $(a_n(x))_n$ is not convergent in 
$K(x)$ by showing that $f(x)\not\in K(x)$.

Given $m$ and $S$ non-negative integers, choose 
$n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $S<(n-1)^2<n^2-m<n^2<n^2+m<(n+1)^2$.
By putting $\ell:=n^2-m$ we have $$S<(n-1)^2<\ell<\ell+m=n^2<\ell+2m<(n+1)^2.$$
Since all the members of an anti-diagonal of $A_{\ell,m}$ are equal, it follows that, 
$$A_{\ell,m}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} $$

and $N_{\ell,m}\neq0$ with $\ell>S$. Then by Theorem, $f(x)\not\in K(x).$

Comment: Hagen von Eitzen gives a shorter proof for $\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^{i^2} \notin K(x)$ in [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1732010/96384) to [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/228422/96384).