# Whether some positive sequence approaches 0 in any ordered field

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, ordered-fields

Consider an ordered field $(\mathbb{F}, +, \times, <)$ with additive identity $0$ and multiplicative identity $1$. It is not hard to show that $1\ne 0$ and then $1=1\times 1>0$.
I am aware that the *Archimedean property* would imply the following function (or sequence, as we are talking about sequential limit) converges to $0$ as $n\to+\infty$.
\begin{align*}
    f:\mathbb{N}&\to\mathbb{F}\\
    n&\mapsto\frac{1}{\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_n}
\end{align*}
However, the *Archimedean property* was just not takend as granted for any ordered field.

Please let me clarify my question to eliminate ambiguities. I am trying to define sequential limit in the following manner:

If $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{F}$ and $L\in\mathbb{F}$ satisfy $\forall \epsilon\in\mathbb{F}^+, \exists N\in\mathbb{N}:\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, \big(n>N\Rightarrow L-\epsilon<f(n)<L+\epsilon\big)$, we shall say that $f(n)\to L$ as $n\to+\infty$. $\mathbb{F}^+$ is defined as $\{x\in\mathbb{F}|x>0\}$.

**My question is, whether any ordered field has a positive sequence ($f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{F}^+$) converging to $0$?**

The question occurs to me when I am trying to prove the equivalence of some forms of *completeness axiom* each of which characterizes $\mathbb{R}$, and I have decided to consider these axioms on some general ordered field $\mathbb{F}$ instead of on $\mathbb{Q}$. Of course, perhaps it's my naive way of proving that somehow encounters with the existence of such an auxiliary sequence (which may take place of common positive sequences in $\mathbb{Q}$ like $n^{-1}$ or $2^{-n}$), as a declaimer.

I am curious of such an answer. On top of that, I wish that it could be **more detailed**, as I am not totally familiar with the rich treasury of counter-examples in Mathematics. Anyway, any help will be appreciated :)

#### Some of my attempts (not necessary to read)

I am aware that we may make a copy of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{F}$ by considering ‘positive integers’ in the form of $\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_n$, then ‘integers’, then ‘rational numbers’. The hypothetical setback is that an $\epsilon\in\mathbb{F}^+$ does not necessarily corresponds to some ‘positive rational number’. I am trying to consider some ordered field with no *Archimedean property*, such as the one mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2929685/does-the-above-non-archimedean-but-ordered-field-satisfy-nested-interval-propert), and I am aware that  $\frac{1}{\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_n}$ does not converge to $0$ in this sense, as we may consider $\epsilon=\frac{1}{x}\in(\mathbb{R}(x))^+$. However, as I am trying to figure out a counter-example, I started to think of the diagonal argument, and so I am not able to construct a counter-example after all, though it may obviously due to the fact that I am not very experienced in dealing with $\mathbb{R}(x)$.

Comment: Have you tried to look at some classical [Non-Archimedean ordered fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Archimedean_ordered_field) and look at their behavior regarding your question?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I am aware of one of them (as in the session ‘Some of my attempts’), but I have not yet succeeded in constructing a counter-example.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Thank you for the fact that $\frac{1}{n}$ does not converge at all. I am aware of that it does not converge to $0$.

Comment: @TonyMa If $\lvert f(n)\rvert\to 0$, then $\frac1{\lvert f(n)\rvert}$ is cofinal in the order $(\Bbb F,<)$. It's quite easy to devise ordered fields of arbitrarily large cofinality. Namely, consider a total order $(W,\le)$ (you can take for instance the ordinal $\omega_1$), and consider the total order on $\Bbb F:=\Bbb R(X_w\,:\, w\in W)$ induced by requiring that $w<y\Rightarrow X_w<X_y$ and $X_w\ge n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$. Then, $\operatorname{cof}(\Bbb F)=\max\{\operatorname{cof}W, \aleph_0\}$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio You should probably turn that into an answer.