# How to prove that field of rational functions is a *proper* subset of field of formal Laurent series?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, laurent-series

> Now, if $F$ is a field, I can prove easily that $F(x)\subseteq F((x))$ but I'm having problems to show this is a proper inclusion.

If for example $F=\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, I can take a well-known function, say $\cos x$ and use its power series to show proper inclusing, because if

$$\left(F((x))\ni\right)\;\cos x=1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{24}-\cdots=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\in F(x)$$

then, since $f(x),g(x)\in F[x]$ (polynomials), we'd get that $\cos x$ has a finite number of zeros, which is absurd, and thus $\cos x\in F((x))\setminus F(x)$.

My problem now is: what to do if the field $F$ is *not* one of the usual, infinite ones? For example, if $F$ has positive characteristic?

Any input will be duly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe we can consider the square root of $x$, perhaps?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with using transcendence degree, but that seems like one possibility to be ruled out. Is the transcendence degree of $F((x))$ over $F$ always greater than that of $F(x)$ over $F$?

Answer (score 8):

An easy argument : $1-x$ has a square root in $F((x))$ but not in $F(x)$.

Indeed, in $F((x))$, take the usual Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{1-x}$ at $0$. But in $F(x)$, looking at decomposition in irreducible factors easily shows that such a square root can't exist.

If the characteristic of $F$ is $2$, this won't work, you will have to take a cubic root.

Maybe I can comment a little on the argument : what I'm using is the fact that $F((x))$ is henselian, whereas $F(x)$ is not. This is a quite different argument from the one by @user26857 : they use the fact that some elements of $F((x))$ are *not* solutions of algebraic equations (over $F(x)$), I use the fact that some elements of $F((x))$ *are* solutions of such equations. This is really a different argument because there are henselian extensions of $F(x)$ which are algebraic over $F$ (namely the henselianization).

Comment: Thank you. I can't see "easily" that, and as someone pointed out in the other link about other series: how can we be sure the denominators $\;n!\;$ (or whatever, depending on the exponent, of course) in the development of $\;\sqrt{1-x}\;$ don't vanish in some field of positive characteristic?

Comment: For the fact the $1-x$ is not a square in $F(x)$, it's exactly the same proof as in $F[x]$ : any square in $F(x)$ must have an even exponent for $(x-1)$ in its irreducible factors decomposition, but $1-x$ has an odd exponent (namely $1$). For the expansion of $\sqrt{1-x}$, I guess you can check on the formula that the denominators are powers of $2$, so in a field of characteristic not $2$ the series will be well-defined. I know it must be so because of Hensel's lemma (and for the same reason the denominators for $(1-x)^{1/3}$ must be powers of $3$ so it will work in characteristic $2$).

Comment: Thank you very much, excellent explanatory comment. +1

Answer (score 0):

We prove a very weak version of the result. Let $F$ be a finite field, and let $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ be a rational function with coefficients in $F$.

Do a formal division of $f$ by $g$. There are only finitely many polynomials of degree less than the degree of $g$ with coefficients in $F$. Thus the formal division yields a terminating or ultimately periodic formal Laurent series.

Now let $q(x)$ be a "sparse" Laurent series, say with the coefficient of $x^n$ equal to $1$ if $n$ is a perfect square, and $0$ otherwise. This is not ultimately periodic.

Comment: I'm probably being stupid, but how do you know that $q$ is not $f/g$ for some $f$ and $g$ whose coefficients cannot be chosen in the prime field?

Comment: @RobArthan: You are right, proof is needed. I do not have the time right now (and may not be able to give a proof) so I have greatly weakened the answer.

Comment: @RobArthan A fellow graduate student of mine wrote a dissertation which included content on the problem of discerning the rational elements in the Laurent series, and I remember feeling like the task was deeper than one might expect.

Comment: Glad I wasn't being too stupid $\ddot{\smile}$. Your proof is nice for finite $F$, but in that case you can also use cardinality: $F(x)$ is countable but $F((x))$ is not.

Comment: The Taylor coefficients of a rational function satisfy a linear recurrence with constant coefficients of some length. It follows that any series which has large gaps (like $\sum x^{n^2})$ is not a rational function. This is a slight generalization of the argument given here.